# Sony DSC-QX10 setAFPosition - 403

Tags: camera, sony

After upgrading to the newest firmware, I recognized that there are new API-calls for the DSC-QX10.

I am interested in the `setTouchAFPosition` API call, but I am not allowed to call it.

The error response I get:

```
{
   "error" : [ 403, "setTouchAFPosition" ],
   "id" : 1
}
```

The request I send:

```
{
   "method":"setTouchAFPosition",
   "params":[77.08333333333334,60.06944444444444],
   "id":1,
   "version":"1.0"
}
```

Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for Touch AF Camera Remote API has been added to DSC-QX10 and DSC-QX100 cameras.
Please try again after updating to latest QX10 firmware (Ver3.0 or later).

Best Regards,
Prem, Member of Developer World team at Sony.

Answer (score 0):

This API call along with many others are intentionally made unavailable by Sony. I think you need some kind of developer ID which you pass in a call to their API method actEnableMethods.